# Where to host a .cur image?

Tags: web-hosting, image-hosting

`.cur` is an image extension for mouse cursors.

I have purchased a custom domain via Blogger. Unlike WordPress, Blogger does not have any directory of webfiles or something where things can be uploaded.

I need to change the default cursor of my mouse in my website. Unfortunately, Google's Picasa or Imageshack/Phobucket do not support `.cur` files.

I found some other image sites while googling but all are old image hosting services which no longer exist.

I tried Dropbox, Google code but they provide a link to download the `.cur` image and not actually give a URL which I can link in my CSS.

Is there any way to host `.cur` images?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the file is just downloading rather than processing correctly is that you  need to setup the [MIME](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full) list to support this. It's doubtful that this is possible on Google Code or Picassa and you will need to use a proper hosting account or a CDN that allows adding of custom MIME.

You'd need to use the following MIME code `image/vnd.microsoft.icon .cur .ico`

Answer (score 1):

[The answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987392/where-to-host-a-cur-image):

Do you really need to keep this file in the `.cur` format? Isn't converting it to, say, `.png` an option?

I'm not even sure every browser/OS out there supports `.cur` (though I've seen examples online with this format, so I might be mistaken). Converting to a more standard format might ensure better portability, besides saving you the hassle of looking for a host with such specific requirements.